# How do I gracefully handle variable-length text coming in from the network in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have variable-length text coming in from network requests to display in a UTableView. They don't come in all at once, so I don't know the length of all the text blocks at once, just when each one comes in. Think of it like a Twitter stream, but the tweets have to be requested individually.

How would I display this elegantly in a UITableView? I want to display them as they come in, but if I'm recalculating cell height each time, I'd be throwing around the user's scroll position a ton, which would be very annoying.

How would I handle this elegantly, perhaps with maintaining scroll offset somehow?

Comment: maybe you need to write some code as starting point of help

Comment: @sage444 seems more like an abstract question not necessarily asking for explicit code

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    MyObject *obj = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGFloat cellHeight;
    if ([self getExpectedLabelSizeForString:obj.textValue].height/15 < 2) {
        cellHeight = 55.0;
    }
    else{
        cellHeight = 35 + ([self getExpectedLabelSizeForString:obj.textValue].height - [self getExpectedLabelSizeForString:obj.textValue].height/15);
    }
    return cellHeight;
}


- (CGSize)getExpectedLabelSizeForString:(NSString *)string{

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(208,FLT_MAX)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:attributesDictionary
                                        context:nil];

    CGSize size = frame.size;
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you support iOS8+, you could use auto-size cells. 
set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and add top, left, right(or width) and bottom constrains to cell's `contentView`. Also add some offsets.
Cell will automatically grow.